# Xcode: alternative way to create segue from control not using Control+drag?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am running Xcode 4.3.3 over a VNC connection to a Max OSX box where Control+drag does not work. I would like to create a segue triggered from a button on the first scene. The usual way is to do control+drag from button to second scene but that does not work because of VNC. Is there an alternative way to do this? For creating outlets there is a workaround by right click on a control and dragging from the list of events to VC's sources code. Is there similar workaround for triggering segues?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's a UIButton, right click on it, you'll see a triggered segue option. Click on the round circle on the right side of it and drag it to the destination.

If it's a viewController, right click on the ViewController thing next to the First Responder (Orange box), you'll see also triggered segue option. Click on the round circle on the right side of it and drag it to the destination to create a segue.